# How to automate a webpage which sends OTP for verification

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am trying to automate Paytm. After entering username and password,it is asking for OTP for verification which will be sent to our registered mobile nnumber.How can we automate this. Can i expect some help?

Comment: your question is too broad.  Also share what you have tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using any automation tool you can't automate as OTP is getting to your mobile number, to avoid the automation these otp or captcha pages were introduced. If you are belong to paytm employee then you can avoid calling that otp dialog box or page by setting or generating cookies I guess.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If your employee of paytm you can access database have the OTP data then you can extract data from database and pass the data .If you don't have any access you cant.

Answer (score 0):

```
String userProfile= "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--user-data-dir="+userProfile);
            options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox");
```

The above code is working fine to Automate the OTP verification webpages. Just create your local chrome trusted one time and call same browser using above code for testing.